# Non-Laravel directory inside Laravel Public directory not working

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have created a custom non-laravel `admin` directory inside laravel 9 `public` directory.

My project at example.com working fine, but when I open that ( `example.com/admin` ), it is redirecting to `example.com/public/admin` and giving me error `HTTP ERROR 500`

Why I am getting this error and what should be updated ?

Tried updating .htaccess file by googling whereever possible

Comment: 500 is a server error, check error logs.

Comment: looks like you're hosting on a shared hosting! You need to add ``RewriteBase /app-folder`` in the .htaccess file.

Comment: In your Laravel project, you might need to update the .htaccess file. Make sure the RewriteBase is set correctly